# 502 gateway error while clicking on one menu-Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have one drupal website when I clicked on one menu it is showing 502 gateway ngnix error but when i click the same menu like

```
?q=videos
```

it is working fine,Please help me why it is showing like this i have search and try to figure out but didn't get success.

Comment: in your host configuration , check if you have activate RewriteEngine On

Answer (score 0):

you didnt enable "clean URL's". you have to be administrator to enable this option.

1. Navigate to the Clean URLs configuration page (Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs)
2. Wait for the automated Clean URLs test to run.
3. Check or uncheck the Enable clean URLs checkbox
4. Click "Save configuration"

here the D7 docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls

Comment: I have enabled thats why other menu is fine only in this menu I am facint the issue